# How to extract elements from `head` section of HTML string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable (`s`) which holds entire HTML document (as a string). I would like to extract some elements from its `head` section. With `body` it is not a problem, I pack entire data into jQuery variable and call `find`.

But with `head` section is different story. When I pack it to jQuery object I can see it creates an array for it, and I see the elements I would like to extract (so to this point it works as I would wish). But when I run `find` against it, jQuery ignores `head` and its content entirely.

So how to extract the elements from the `head`?

*Just for the record, **currently** I am trying to extract `link` nodes to get urls for CSS files.*

Comment: why can't you just do `$("link");`?

Comment: @Prisoner, do you refer to using `find` method? Because it is not current document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For top level elements in your DOM, it seems you have to use filter() instead of find().

```
var html = $.parseHTML('<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/inuit.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/inuit.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/inuit.css"></head><body></body></html>');

$(html).filter("link").each(function(i, link) {
    alert(link);  
});
```

This alerts the three links from the string.

Answer (score 1):

For the URL of your CSS files, this regexp should do the trick:

```
var patt = /.*<link(.*href="(.*)"|.*rel="stylesheet"|.*type="text\/css"){1,}.*>.*/gi;
var array_of_ccs_files = head_as_str.match(patt);
for (var i = 1; i < array_of_ccs_files.length; ++i) {
    console.log(array_of_ccs_files[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This one works, I will a bit longer though, maybe someone will come up with regular DOM approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can just query the jQuery object for it...

```
var sHtmlString = ....;
var oDom = $(sHtmlString);
oDom.find("head > link");
```

Comment: Thank you, I checked it, but nothing outside `body` works. I cannot even use `find` for `body`, the only valid elements to search for, are the nodes within `body` (at least it looks like that).

Comment: You're right, it works on a DOM but not on a parsed string :S Vanilla document fragments seem to have the same restrictions too.